# Why are some of our company's mails being sent to junk folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In my company we have a list of 10 emails called STUFF. We also use Outlook 2010 for our emails. My question is that when we try to send an email from our main email info@companyname.com to all of the STUFF contacts, some of them receive the email in the junk folder. Why this happens? What do you propose me to check?

Comment: You need to contact these contacts and have them adjust their spam software not whitelist your company.  There is no enough information to determine the reason your email would be considered spam.

Answer (score 1):

If they are also using Outlook, it's junk processing is ... well ... junk!

We have terrible problems with it junking perfectly legitimate emails even from within our own domains! As @Ramhound says though, this is generally an issue that can only be dealt with at the recipient end.

All you can do is to try and change your email content so that it doesn't look so much like SPAM. Look carefully at the content and try to spot things that might be spammy. Items about winning, discount, "Dear Sir", and much more are used by spammers.